# How do I set up Cloud9 to use ffmpeg?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, ffmpeg, cloud9-ide, moviepy

I have a local python script using `moviepy` that stitches together images to make a movie.  I'd like to move this into a lambda function.

My approach has been to use AWS Cloud9 IDE to create the lambda.  But I am stuck getting ffmpeg to work.  moviepy is looking for ffmpeg, but I can't install it.

Specifically when running the function with just `import moviepy`, Cloud9 errors with

> [ERROR] RuntimeError: No ffmpeg exe could be found. Install ffmpeg on your system, or set the IMAGEIO_FFMPEG_EXE environment variable.

And when trying to install ffmpeg (`sudo yum install ffmpeg`), Cloud9 prevents with the message

> 234 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
>
> No package ffmpeg available.

How do I get Cloud9 to contain a usable ffmpeg that I can call in my python script?  Or, alternatively, is there a more cloud-friendly way to stitch images to a video?

**Update: installed binary, get similar error**

Installing the binary lets me import `moviepy` and run commands.  But on trying to write the result file, I get the following error

> Moviepy - Building video ~/tmp/movie.mp4. Moviepy - Writing video
> ~/tmp/movie.mp4
>
> [ERROR] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/usr/bin/ffmpeg' Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/var/task/app.py", line 52, in lambda_handler
>     clip_looped.write_videofile('~/tmp/movie.mp4')   File "", line 2, in write_videofile   File
> "/var/task/moviepy/decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration
>     return f(clip, *a, **k)   File "", line 2, in write_videofile   File "/var/task/moviepy/decorators.py", line 135, in
> use_clip_fps_by_default
>     return f(clip, *new_a, **new_kw)   File "", line 2, in write_videofile   File "/var/task/moviepy/decorators.py", line
> 22, in convert_masks_to_RGB
>     return f(clip, *a, **k)   File "/var/task/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py", line 300, in write_videofile
>     ffmpeg_write_video(self, filename, fps, codec,   File "/var/task/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_writer.py", line 213, in
> ffmpeg_write_video
>     with FFMPEG_VideoWriter(filename, clip.size, fps, codec = codec,   File "/var/task/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_writer.py", line 129, in
> **init**
>     self.proc = sp.Popen(cmd, **popen_params)   File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in **init**
>     self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,   File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in
> _execute_child
>     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)

Comment: I don't know much about cloud anything, but can you upload the ffmpeg binary (which you can download off ffmpeg.org) and set it up yourself?

Comment: I tried that, so now `moviepy` imports!  And I can even run some commands (ImageSequenceClip) but saving (write_videofile) generates what seems like a similar error: No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/ffmpeg'

Comment: But when I got to /usr/bin, ffmpeg is there

Comment: Again it could be the file permission issue. Without seeing the exact error, you are likely writing your output file to a folder which ffmpeg cannot write to.

Comment: Added the error message in the question.  Permissions would make sense, since it errors on the writing a new file.  But the error states it can't find ffmpeg in the very place it is located.